# Condition operator "?:" and LPCTSTR in function header

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

Maybe anyone can explain this to me:

```
bool Func1(LPCTSTR sData)
{
    if (sData) { ... }
}
```

And I called the function like this:

```
CString str = _T("");
Func1((str.IsEmpty() ? NULL : str));
```

And 'sData' inside function is never NULL, it is allways empty string but not NULL, why?
Eddited code like this:

```
LPCTSTR strNull = NULL;
Func1((str.IsEmpty() ? strNull : str));
```

In this case it works correct.

Comment: `Func1((str.IsEmpty() ? NULL : str));` doesn't compile on VS2015, I get `Error C2446 ':': no conversion from 'CString' to 'int' ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the need to convert both the second and third operands to a common type.
(The result can't have different types depending on whether the condition is true or not.)

The first parameter is equivalent to

```
str.IsEmpty() ? CString(NULL) : str
```

since `NULL` doesn't have a type that you convert a `CString` to.
And `CString(NULL)` constructs an empty `CString`.

The second is equivalent to

```
str.IsEmpty() ? strNull : (LPCTSTR) str
```

since `CString` is convertible to `LPCTSTR` but not the other way around.

Inlining the cast,

```
    str.IsEmpty() ? (LPCTSTR) NULL : str
```

should give the same effect as the second.

Comment: And I'm still confused how the [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cws1zdt8.aspx) c'tor is resolved in the expression `CString(NULL)`. There are several c'tors that take pointer arguments. How does the compiler pick one (and which one is it)?

Comment: I get it now: All c'tors taking a single pointer argument are `explicit`, except for the one taking a `const XCHAR*`.

Answer (score 5):

The conditional operator converts its second and third arguments to a type that's common to the two of them. I don't know the details of `CString`, so this is just a guess, but it looks like the conditional operator converts `NULL` to a `CString` to match the type of the third argument, and passes that, through an implicit conversion to `LPCTSTR`, to the function.

Comment: `CString` does have an implicit conversion operator ([CSimpleStringT::operator PCXSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk1z2hd9.aspx)). I still don't quite follow, how the [CStringT::CStringT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cws1zdt8.aspx) constructor is resolved. There are more than one that matches a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I imagine that

```
Func1((str.IsEmpty() ? (LPCTSTR)NULL : str));
```

would also work, and if it does, you probably have a type casting problem which was fixed by the

```
LPCTSTR strNull = NULL;
```

assignment because it will associate the type `LPCTSTR` with the value of null when `strNull` is called later.